# Best way implementing infinite scrolling with Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I found some good answers about infinite horizontal scrolling
But what I would like to do is an infinite scrolling background, horizontal and vertical.
So far I thought about setting 9 backgrounds and replace 3 of each every time one goes away from the screen.
Can anyone tell me if this is the best solution or if there is other easier way to do this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: By "best way" I always read "working solution" so this will work, yes. Best is relative, subjective, depends a whole lot on your app's requirements and target platforms and almost always can not be assessed without actually implementing and testing all possible ways of doing *that* thing (whatever it may be). So just pick the working solution, and optimize later (if needed). Lastly, finish this sentence: "Premature optimization is ..." ;)

Comment: ...the root of all evil.
Interesting :)
Maybe by 'best way' I meant 'a better way' if anyone has tried this earlier ;)
Thanks for your comment